# Is this set a Vector Space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}$ a vector space? Answer is no. Let me try;

In order to be a vector space, the following two criteria must be satisfied:

1) $\forall u\in \mathbb{V}, \forall v\in \mathbb{V}, \exists ! u\oplus v\in V$

2) $\forall u\in \mathbb{V}, a\in \mathbb{R}, \exists ! a\odot v\in V$

The sum of two such matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}$+$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &2a\\ 
 2b&2 
\end{pmatrix}$=$2\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}$. How can this, for given $a,b\in R$, NOT be uniquely defined?

I do know that $u$ and $v$ are vectors so if we let:

$u=(1,b),\ \ v=(a,1)$ then $u+v=(1+a,b+1)$ which for given $a,b$ also uniquely defined.

Comment: It is uniquely defined; however, it's not contained in $V$.

Comment: I don't follow. V contains the whole set \begin{pmatrix}
1 &a \\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}, $a,b\in R$. So I fail to see how it's not contained in V..

Comment: $2\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 &2a\\ 
 2b&2 
\end{pmatrix}$ which is not of the given form, since it has $2$s on the diagonal, not $1$s.

Comment: To be a vector (sub-) space, you are missing a requirement that ensures you don't have the empty set. In your example you have not got the empty set, but I think the usual way to ensure not having the empty set is to require the zero vector to be in the set. With that definition this should be a no-brainer.

Comment: @AdamYac Did you want to establish whether or not $V$ is a subspace of the vector space $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ of real $2 \times 2$ matrices, or did you want to establish whether or not the set $V$ admitted any vector space structure? If the former, V-X's answer is what you want, but if the latter, Donkey_2009's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify what is your task!

$u =\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a_1\\ 
 b_1&1 
\end{pmatrix}$

$v = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &a_2\\ 
 b_2&1 
\end{pmatrix}$

$u + v = \begin{pmatrix}
2 &a_1 + a_2\\ 
 b_1 + b_2&2 
\end{pmatrix}$

$u + v \notin V$

This means V is not a vector space.

Comment: why can't you devide by $2$?

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2, and two can be divided by two, thus you are adding 1 + 1 = 1?

Comment: oh sry my fault that was a stupid one

Answer (score 6):

The set does not contain the zero matrix. Hence it is not a vector space (under usual matrix addition).

Answer (score 4):

$V$ is a vector space under the following addition and scalar multiplication (which are **not** the usual addition and scalar multiplication for matrices):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a_1\\ 
 b_1&1 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
1 &a_2\\ 
 b_2&1 
\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a_1+a_2\\ 
 b_1+b_2&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 
 b&1 
\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
1 &\lambda a\\ 
 \lambda b&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, under the usual matrix addition/scalar multiplication it is not a subspace of the space of $2\times 2$ real matrices, so it is not a vector space (as V-X has pointed out).

Comment: you have to define specific addition/multiplication operator, but in this case, it seemed to be defined as usual.